# Pass value from php to Jscript

Tags: php, html, jscript

I have below code.
I am getting time from other page via get method into feedback.php.

Now I need to pass this value from feedback.php to chart.js on this line **['Time taken by you is', time]**   then it will dispay chart on feedback.php page. How  can I get this things done?

feedback.php

```
 <script src="chart.js"></script>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>
 <div id="chart_div"></div>

  **<?php $time= $_GET["sec"];?><br>**
```

chart.js

```
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Time taken by worker'],
    ['Worker 1 ', 200],
    ['Worker 2', 150],
    ['Worker 3', 300],
    ['Worker 4', 160],
    ['Worker 5', 140],
    ['Time taken by you is', time]
  ]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below

**Define Time Var before load chart.js**

```
<script>
    var TIME_VAR = '<?=$_GET["sec"];?>';
 </script>
```

**Then load** `<script src="chart.js"></script>`

In **chart.js** you can use **TIME_VAR**

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Time', 'Time taken by worker'],
    ['Worker 1 ', 200],
    ['Worker 2', 150],
    ['Worker 3', 300],
    ['Worker 4', 160],
    ['Worker 5', 140],
    ['Time taken by you is',TIME_VAR]
  ]);
```

Comment: Working perfectly :)